# Generalization of a rule to n arguments

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement, symbolic, code-generation

I am trying to apply a series expansion on a function `x[t1, t2,...tn]`, with an expansion parameter `a`. For `n = 2`, the function is `x[t1, t2]`, and this is my series expansion:

```
solRule2 = x -> (Sum[a^i Subscript[x, i][#1, #2], {i, 0, 2}] &);
x[t1, t2] /. solRule2
```

The result is given correctly as

> Subscript[x, 0][t1, t2] + a Subscript[x, 1][t1, t2] + a^2 Subscript[x, 2][t1, t2]

This works also with derivatives, and this matters to me:

```
(x^(2,0))[t1,t2]/. solRule2
```

> (Subscript[x, 0]^(2, 0))[t1, t2] + a (Subscript[x, 1]^(2,0))[t1, t2] + a^2 (Subscript[x, 2]^(2, 0))[t1, t2]

Now, I can manually extend the rule to `n = 3`,

```
solRule3 = x -> (Sum[a^i Subscript[x, i][#1, #2, #3], {i, 0, 3}] &);
```

but what I want to do is to extend it to the generic `n`. I tried this

```
solRuleN = x -> (Sum[a^i Subscript[x, i][##], {i, 0, Length[{##}]}] &);
```

This works well with the function `x[t1,t2]` and in general with `x[t1,t2, ..., tn]`, but it fails with the derivatives:

```
(x^(1, 1))[t1, t2]/.solRuleN
```

gives output `0`. I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Have a look at `Sequence`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem boils down to the fact that

```
Derivative[1][f[##] &]
```

> 0 &

Which is, in my opinion unexpected. More in: [**Derivative of a pure function with SlotSequence**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99439/5478)

---

**The fix** is to inject a sequence of `Slots (#1, #2...)` of length equal to the number of arguments our function accepts:

```
series[n__] := With[{
    l = Length[{n}],
    slots = Array[Slot, Length[{n}]]
  },
  Sum[a^i Subscript[x, i] @@ slots, {i, 0, l}] &
]

solRuleN = {
   x[t__] :> series[t],
   Derivative[n__][x] :> Derivative[n][series[n]]
}; 


Derivative[1, 1, 1][x][t1, t2, t3] /. solRuleN
```

> ```
> (Subscript[x, 0]^(1,1,1))[t1,t2,t3]+a (Subscript[x, 1]^(1,1,1))[t1,t2,t3]+a^2 (Subscript[x, 2]^(1,1,1))[t1,t2,t3]+a^3 (Subscript[x, 3]^(1,1,1))[t1,t2,t3]
> ```

Comment: slightly more concise: `series[n__] := Length[{n}] /. l_ :> (Array[Slot, l] /. slots_ :> (Sum[a^i Subscript[x, i] @@ slots, {i, 0, l}] &))`