# Derivative of a pure function with SlotSequence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I can live with this but I can't figure out why the following is `0`:

```
Derivative[1][f[##] &][x]
```

> 0

From documentation for `Derivative`:

> [...] **Whenever** `Derivative[n][f]` is generated, the WL rewrites it as `D[f[#],{#,n}]&`. [...]

but

```
D[f[##] &[#], {#, 1}] &[x]
```

> f'[x]

So where is this `0` from?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe there are at least three cases treated separately by `Derivative`.

*1) A function defined by a `Symbol`.*
This follows the the rule cited in the documentation.

```
g[x___] := f[x];
Derivative[1][g][x] // Trace

(*
 { { g'
   , { g[#1]                    <-- Here the rule is being applied
     , f[#1] }
   , f'[#1] & }
 , (f'[#1] &)[x]
 , f'[x] }
*)
```

*2) A function defined by `Function`, with explicit symbolic arguments.*
This one cannot mimic `f[##] &`, but it seems to be a special case not handled in the way explained in the documentation; rather, the body is differentiated directly.

```
Derivative[1][Function[{x}, f[x]]][x] // Trace

(*
 { { Function[{x}, f[x]]'
   , Function[{x}, f'[x]] }    <-- Differentiates the body
 , Function[{x}, f'[x]][x]
 , f'[x]}
*)
```

*3) A "pure" `Function` (the OP's case).*
This also is handled by direct differentiation of the body, with respect to `Slot[1]`.  In the OP's example, the expression does not (symbolically) depend on `Slot[1]`, so its derivative is zero.
Apparently, rewriting `SlotSequence` in terms of `Slot`, say, in accord with the number of arguments passed to `Derivative` was either rejected or not considered in the design of `Derivative`.

```
Derivative[1][f[##] &][x] // Trace

(*
 { { (f[##1] &)'
   , 0 & }                     <-- Differentiates the body
 , (0 &)[x]
 , 0}
*)
```

The following is equivalent to my view of how `Derivative` works:

```
deriv[n__][f_] := f /. {
   HoldPattern[Function[body_]] :>
     With[{dbody = D[body, Sequence @@ Transpose@ {Array[Slot, Length@{n}], {n}}]},
       Function[dbody]],
   HoldPattern[Function[vars_List, body_]] /; Length[vars] == Length[{n}] :>
     With[{dbody = D[body, Sequence @@ Transpose@ {vars, {n}}]}, 
      Function[vars, dbody]],
   HoldPattern[ff_] :>
     With[{vars = Array[Slot, Length@{n}]}, 
      Evaluate@ D[ff @@ vars, Sequence @@ Transpose@ {vars, {n}}] &]}

deriv[1][g][x]
deriv[1][Function[{x}, f[x]]][x]
deriv[1][f[##] &][x]
(*
  Derivative[1][f][x]
  Derivative[1][f][x]
  0
*)
```

Comment: Isn't then documentation wrong? "Whenever" is missleading.

Comment: @Kuba, yes.  At best it is vague. (What sort of expression does `f` represent? What it mean by "generated"? "Generated" does not sound like it refers to user input.)

Answer (score 11):

Consider

```
 Derivative[1][f[##] &] // FullForm
```

> `Function[0]`

```
 Function[0][x]
```

> `0`

So the snippet you quote from the docs might not be entirely accurate; might not be considering such an edge case as `##`.

I believe that `Derivative` is looking for head `Slot` when detects a pure function goes on to rewrite it, so it ignores head `SlotSequence` -- i.e., treats it same as it would treat head `u` in

```
 Derivative[1][f[u[1]] &][x]
```

> `0`