# Why is `g[#1, #2] &` different from `g[##] &` for a function with two variables in this example?

Tags: pure-function

If we only consider functions with two variables, I expect `g[#1, #2] &` is the same as `g[##] &`. But in the following example, they are not the same. Why?

```
expr = f[x, y] + D[f[x, y], x]
(* -> f[x, y] + Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] *)

expr /. f -> (g[#1, #2] &)
(* -> g[x, y] + Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y] *)

expr /. f -> (g[##] &)
(* -> g[x, y] *)
```

Comment: I was confused too! [Derivative of a pure function with SlotSequence](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99439/5478)