# How to obtain the Derivative of a pure Function of variable number of arguments?

Tags: function-construction

Here is a function `f` that takes a variable number of arguments:

```
f = Times[##]*Log[1 - Times[##]] &
```

I now want to functionally take the derivative:

```
Derivative[1,0,0][f]
```

I expect:

```
(*  Log[1 - #1 #2 #3] #2 #3 - (#1 #2^2 #3^2)/(1 - #1 #2 #3) & *)
```

Instead I get the zero function:

```
(*  0 &  *)
```

I want to act like how it does on built-in variable functions like `Power` or `Times`:

```
Derivative[1, 0, 0][Power]
(*  #1^(-1 + #2^#3) #2^#3 & *)

Derivative[1, 0, 0][Times]
(*  #2 #3 & *)
```

How do I elegantly take the derivative of a pure function?

---

**Motivation**:  I want to define the `Derivative` of another user-defined function in terms of `f`, like this:

```
Derivative[args__Integer][userFunction] := Derivative[args][f]
```

Comment: at least closely related: [Derivative of a pure function with SlotSequence](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99439/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about your motivation, but the following definition seems to do what you need: [BlankNullSequence](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) (`BlankSequence` will work too)

```
f[x___] := Times[x]*Log[1 - Times[x]];
Derivative[1, 0, 0][f]

(*Log[1 - #1 #2 #3] #2 #3 - (#1 #2^2 #3^2)/(1 - #1 #2 #3) &*)
```