# How to use a function definition in another function

Tags: functions, evaluation

For example (not what I really need but will fur sure answer my question)

```
f[x_]:=Sin[x];
der[x_]:=D[f[x],x]
```

At least this was my idea, but it does not work at all. You can see that the definition of `der[x]` includes the definition of another function. And I want to get its derivative.

Comment: Use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`: `der[x_] = D[f[x], x]` or use `Evaluate`: `der[x_] := Evaluate@D[f[x], x]`. In either case, afterwards look at `?der`

Comment: Your function works as expected for me. If you want to evaluate functions of the form `Sin[u]` change `der` to `der[u_, x_] := D[f[u], x]`, allowing you to call `der[x^2, x]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So this is an evaluation order problem, my quick fix would be to do the derivative using a different variable then substitute x back in at the end:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x];
der[x_] := D[f[y], y] /. y -> x;
der[.5]
(*0.877583*)
```

Comment: One would do well to make `y` local via `Module` I think, or use a Formal Symbol.  +1 however.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I believe a formal symbol would suffer the same pitfall as `Slot[1]` in my answer (e.g. `Sin[\[FormalY] * x]`).  Since a formal symbol is more likely to be used as a parameter than `Slot[]`, perhaps it is less safe.

Comment: @Michael If I follow your logic the session-unique `Module` variable is OK however, correct?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, it should be. It seems the system will bump the module number up if someone decides `y$13214` is their favorite parameter name, and the next module number is `13214`.  So a conflict shouldn't arise, AFAICT.

Comment: I can confirm that in my case wrapping the body in a `Module` was what I needed for the gradient of a bivariate function `f`, like `gradfun[x_, y_] := 
  Module[{a, b}, D[f[a, b], {{a, b}}] /. {a -> x, b -> y}];`. Very helpful tip, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Two more ways:

```
der[x_] := f'[x];

der[x_] := With[{df = D[f[#], #]}, df &[x]];
```

The second way follows the way the system implements `f'` (`Derivative`), so they're as safe as *Mathematica*.
However, both solutions above suffer the same restriction that `Derivative` does:

This is okay:

```
ff[x_] := Sin[3 * x];
der[x_] := ff'[x];
der[x]
(*  3 Cos[3 x]  *)
```

But not this:

```
ff[x_] := Sin[# * x];
der[x_] := ff'[x];
der[x]
(*  2 x Cos[x^2]  *)
```

What happened to the coefficient `#`???  (For a hint, use [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html).)

You can check directly that `ff'[x]` misbehaves:

```
ff'[x]
D[ff[x], x]
(*
  2 x Cos[x^2]
  Cos[x #1] #1
*)
```

Moral: `Slot[]` is not safe as a parameter when differentiating.

Comment: See also this Q&A: [(99439)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99439)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
f = Sin[#] &
der = D[#, x] &
der[f[x]]
```

or this

```
der[f_[x]] = d[f[x], x]
l[x_] = a x + b x^2
der[l[x]]
```

Normally your definition should works --- it works on my computer. Restart the kernel.